# call and send parameters to GET method in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have following GET method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
    {
       .......
    }
```

and I have form with `#createbrochure` button ID

this is jquery button for that button click

```
        $('#createborchure').click(function () {

            var data = $('#brochureform').serialize();
            var url = '@Url.Action("Create_Brochure")';               

            $.get(url, data, function (result) {                    
                window.location = url;
            });

          });
```

Once I click I want call above `ActionResult` GET method and send `data` but this isn't working now I click button its not sending `data` values

Comment: So is it working or not? what issues are you having?

Comment: this isn't working now I click button its not sending `data` values to get method

Comment: Add the html code (form) as well or at least the actual value of the `data` variable. Also post the definition of `ProductsPropertiesVM` class.

Comment: Did you debug the javascript to see whether data has a proper value? Did you use Fiddler or Postman to see the request sent to the server?

Comment: @ViktorBahtev Here the whole code https://dotnetfiddle.net/5E7s3U

Comment: @venerik data is not just a single value , its extracting from a form which is contain check boxes and its IDs

Comment: Will u specify the controller name in Url.Action `var url = '@Url.Action("Create_Brochure","Home")'`

Comment: @MahbuburRahman, Nope ,I tried ur approach, still model is Null , but this is working once I use `$.post(url, data, function (result) { `.

Comment: It doesn't matter that data is not a single value. You can still inspect it using the developer tools of your browser to be sure it has the values you expect.

Comment: What is the point of this. You do a `$.get()` call to the method (passing the form data), but do nothing with whatever result it returns, and then you do another GET to the same method (the `window.location = url;` line) but this time don't pass any data to it. What is it your actually trying to do?

Comment: Actually I'm using it , `public ActionResult Create_Brochure(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model){            
            IEnumerable<int> selectedIDs = model.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Property_ID);` then I have to load rich text editor with html file inside of it, using this I'm loading that HTML file `editor.LoadHtml("~/brochuretemplates/myhtml.cshtml");` with this `loadhtml ()` I have to append above `selectedIDs` as array to html url

Comment: Then its `$.get(url, data, function (result) { $(someElement).html(result); }` if the `Create_Brochure()` method is returning a partial view. Show the code inside the method and the partial view it returns so we can understand what your trying to do.